# how to use "splncs.bst" style file?

Tags: bibtex, lncs

I have a reviewer asked me to put `splncs.bst` style file in a `lncs` conference paper for bibliography formatting. How should I do this?

Comment: use `\bibliographystyle{splncs} \bibliography{Bibfile}`

Comment: Full LNCS template is available at https://latextemplates.github.io/LNCS/.

Answer (score 2):

You can setup the style via `\bibliographystyle{splncs}`

However you have to make sure that BibTeX can find the bibliography style file. Therefor you can either install the file in your local texmf tree or put the file in you working directory.

The path of you local texmf tree can be detected by:

```
kpsewhich -var-value=TEXMFHOME
```

Related to the rules of a texmf tree you should put your file in the following directory

```
`kpsewhich -var-value=TEXMFHOME`/bibtex/bst/splncs/splncs.bst
```